# Move item in array to 3rd position?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is randomly shuffled with a list of restaurants. I want to keep it that way except move a specific item which has `restaurant_id => 01` for example to always the `3rd` position. How can I achieve that?

```
// Function to sort by open first
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['open_status'] - $b['open_status'];
}

// randomize results
shuffle($data['list']);

$array = $data['list'];

// Sort by open first
usort($array, 'sortByOrder');
```

Where in the code would I add it so that a specific name is always in 3rd position?

The array is like this:

```
array(30) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(1) "01"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(7) "Place 1"
    ["open_status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["restaurant_id"]=>
    string(1) "02"
    ["restaurant_name"]=>
    string(7) "Place 2"
    ["open_status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ...
}
```

So basically the one with `restaurant_id` = `01` would always need to be 3rd.

Comment: Remove it before you sort and then insert it at the 3rd position.

Comment: show the `$array` contents

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Added the array :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the item inside a temporary variable, delete the item from the array, then change the array however you like, then reinsert it.

```
<?php

$data = Array(
    "list" => Array(1,2,3,4)
);

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['open_status'] - $b['open_status'];
}

$temp = $data['list'][2]; //stores item
unset($data['list'][2]); //deletes item
shuffle($data['list']);
$array = $data['list'];
usort($array, 'sortByOrder');

array_splice($array, 2, 0, array($temp)); //re-insert the item

print_r($array);

?>
```